# Cannot create a persistentVolume on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm studying for the CKAD and I'm trying to create a `PersistenVolume` of type `hostPath` on my local minikube cluster and mount to a container

These are the steps:

1. I created a PV of type `hostPath` and `path: "/data/vol1/"`
2. I created a PVC and its state is `Bound`
3. I created a POD and mounted the PVC as volume under "/var/something/"
4. I ran `minikube ssh` and created a file `/data/vol1/foo.bar`
5. I expected to see the file `foo.bar` under the folder /var/something/` of the container, but it's not there.

This is the yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: 1311-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/vol1/"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: 1311-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ex10
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: pvc
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: 1311-pvc
  containers:
  - image: httpd
    name: web
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/var/something/"
      name: pvc
```

And this is the status of the system:

```
k get pvc
NAME       STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
1311-pvc   Bound    pvc-c892f798-8ee6-4040-9177-3e77327e9ec6   1Gi        RWX            standard       5m
```

```
k get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM              STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
1311-pv                                    2Gi        RWX            Retain           Available                                              13m
pvc-c892f798-8ee6-4040-9177-3e77327e9ec6   1Gi        RWX            Delete           Bound       default/1311-pvc   standard                13m
```

```
pod describe ex10

...
 Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-lw45q (ro)
      /var/something/ from pvc (rw)
....
```

Everything looks correct to be, but I don't see the file inside the container:

```
k exec ex10  -- ls /var/something
- no results here -
```

that I created into the minikube vm:

```
ssh minikube

$ ls /data/vol1/
foo.bar
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this issue, the PV must specify the `storageClassName: standard` in order to work.

This is how the PV should look like to properly store data into minikube host

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: 1311-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: "standard"
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  hostPath:
    path: "/host/"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
```